# Small caps in section but not in ToC

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, formatting, small-caps, sections-paragraphs

With LaTeX, I would like to set all my section titles in small capitals but I need the `\textsc` to be 'cancelled' in my table of content. Is that possible somehow ?

I currently do this :

```
\section[Introduction]{\textsc{Introduction}}
```

Is there a automatic way?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 6):

[`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) is a quick way to achieve what you're after *if* you're using one of the standard document classes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}% http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty
\allsectionsfont{\normalfont\scshape}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

---

[`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) provides a similar easy solution via the `sc` package option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sc]{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```