# How do I change the format of one section heading without affecting how it appears in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, fontsize

In one instance in my document I have the following:

```
\section{\large Multi-worded section heading }
```

Currently in the table of contents, it appears larger than all of the other titles (no doubt because that's what I've instructed LaTeX to do).  How do I change this such that it is the same as the other titles?

Comment: Use `\section[Multi-worded section heading]{\large Multi-worded section heading }`

Comment: @HarishKumar Answer, I suppose?  I think the question title should be generalized somewhat, though.

Comment: Why no use `titlesec`?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Small caps in section but not in ToC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170983/5764)

Comment: @skpblack. The OP wants to do it for just one section, I suppose.

Comment: just to note that not all document classes handle sectioning commands vis-a-vis the toc in the same way.  for example, ams document classes do not use the [optional short form] in the toc, but have other mechanisms for dealing with such requirements.  so it's a good idea to be specific about *what* document class is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood this as: you want to change fonts only in one/few of the section titles (not for all). The easiest way is to use the optional argument of `\section` like

```
%\section[optional content]{regular content }    
\section[Multi-worded section heading]{\large Multi-worded section heading }
```

so that optional unformatted content is used for running headings and toc.   Here is the MWE with `article` class (you didn't tell which class!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Some section}
\section[A section]{\Huge A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\section{Some section again}
\end{document}
```

[image]

which certainly looks ugly with a smaller section number. A better way is to define a new command like:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mysection{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}}    %%<-- \Large replaced by \Huge
\makeatother
```

and use it as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mysection{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Some section}
\mysection{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\section{Some section again}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to apply these changes to all the sections, you may better use `sectsty` (as linked by Werner: [Small caps in section but not in ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170983/5764) or use `titlesec` package (`titleformat*{\section}{\Huge}`).