# How to redefine \section{...} to include \textsc{...}?

Tags: sectioning

I'm writing a rather extensive report in LaTeX in which I have some specific preferences for my section titles. For example, I want the titles to be in upper-case using the \textsc{..} command. If I include,

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I am able write,

```
\section{\textsc{Some Section Title}} % works fine, however ...
```

My document is large and it would be really nice if I could redefine `\section{}` to automatically include `\textsc{}`. I'm happy to consider some other alternative to `\textsc{}`, if such exists.

Note that I have no experiance with the '\renewcommand', so working examples are much appriciated! Thanks!

Adding an MWE as requested,

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}             % ENABLES \textsc{} INSIDE \section{}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Roman{subsection}}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}

% IMPORTANT:
% Now, my section titles are centered, and have roman numbering.
% .. but I would also like to have them written in upercase.

\title{The most awesome title ever!}
\author{My name and stuff}
\date{2014}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{\textsc{Section nr. 1}}
% THIS WORKS, but ...
Some text ...    

\section{Section nr. 2}
% I would like to write this with the same result
Some text ...    


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  The way to do this depends on which document class you are using.

Comment: @ChrisS, It does indeed look promising. However could you please help me modify it? How to change "\allsectionsfont{\normalfont\scshape}" to make upper-case. I thought \scshape would do this, but apparently this doesn't work for me (compiles, but titles are still small case)

Comment: You're already using `sectsty`, so turn your `\allsectionsfont{\centering}` into `\allsectionsfont{\centering\mdseries\scshape}`. The `\mdseries` turns off boldface.

Comment: Perfect, solves my problem! Do you think I should the delete question due to double question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by ChrisS, a solution to my question could be made out of this post: [Small caps in section but not in ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170983/small-caps-in-section-but-not-in-toc)

Resulting in the final solution for making the `\section{}` command automatically creating centered, uppercase titles with roman numbering ...

```
\usepackage{sectsty}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Roman{subsection}}
\allsectionsfont{\centering\mdseries\scshape}
```